# addEventListener on Java

Tags: java, jsoup

i have a document  and i want to addEventListener 'click' for button.How can i do that?
I have a code

```
Document doc =Jsoup.connect(url)
       .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36")
       .get(); 
Element button=doc.getElementsByTag("button").first();
EventListener click = new EventListener() {
                @Override
                public void handleEvent(Event evt) {

                };
            };
```

how can i call mouse click

Comment: JSoup is a parser.  You need a browser with a JS engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments already, Jsoup is only a parsing library for HTML. It does not interpret or run any JavaScript. If you need that kind of behavior you can use tools like [selenium webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) or if you are on Java 8 you can use the WebKit engine in JavaFX.